# How to start dragging an item programmatically using dojo/dnd/Moveable?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using [dojo/dnd/Moveable](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dnd/Moveable.html) in order to make an item draggable.
At the moment using the following script:

- user click the button "make movable", div is now draggable
- user has to point and drag on the div in order to start dragging.

I would need change its behavior in the following way:

- user click and keep pressed the button "make movable"
- div is immediately draggable and take the position of the mouse cursor

I have tried using [topic in manager](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dnd.html#summary-of-topics) `/dnd/start` but with no success.

Any ideas how to solve this?

http://jsbin.com/cohalorike/1/

```
require(["dojo/dnd/Moveable", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function (Moveable, dom, on) {

            on(dom.byId('btn'), 'click', function () {
                var dnd = new Moveable(dom.byId("dndOne"));
                on(dnd, "FirstMove", function (event, leftTop) {
                    console.log('FirstMove', leftTop);
                });
                on(dnd, "Move", function (event, leftTop) {
                    console.log('Move', leftTop);
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [`dojo/dnd/Source`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dnd.html#source) instead.